# Assigning to a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Forgive me if this has been asked before.  I did not know how to search for it.

I'm quite familiar with the following idiom:

```
def foo():
    return [1,2,3]

[a,b,c] = foo()
(d,e,f) = foo()
```

wherein the values contained within the left hand side will be assigned based upon the values returned from the function on the right.

I also know you can do

```
def bar():
    return {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

(one, two, three) = bar()
[four, five, six] = bar()
```

wherein the keys returned from the right hand side will be assigned to the containers on the left hand side.

However, I'm curious, is there a way to do the following in Python 2.6 or earlier:

```
{letterA:one, letterB:two, letterC:three} = bar()
```

and have it work in the same manner that it works for sequences to sequences?  If not, why? Naively attempting to do this as I've written it will fail.

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary items do not have an order, so while this works:

```
>>> def bar():
...     return dict(a=1,b=2,c=3)
>>> bar()
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> (lettera,one),(letterb,two),(letterc,three) = bar().items()
>>> lettera,one,letterb,two,letterc,three
('a', 1, 'c', 3, 'b', 2)
```

You can see that you can't necessarily predict how the variables will be assigned.  You could use `collections.OrderedDict` in Python 3 to control this.

Comment: +1 and i want to emphasize the "you can't necessarily predict how the variables will be assigned" part!

Answer (score 1):

If you modify bar() to return a dict (as suggested by @mikerobi), you might want to still preserve keyed items that are in your existing dict.  In this case, use update:

```
mydict = {}
mydict['existing_key'] = 100

def bar_that_says_dict():
    return { 'new_key': 101 }

mydict.update(bar_that_says_dict())

print mydict
```

This should output a dict with both existing_key and new_key.  If mydict had a key of new_key, then the update would overwrite it with the value returned from bar_that_says_dict.

Answer (score -1):

No, if you can not change bar function, you could create a dict from the output pretty easily.

This is the most compact solution.  But I would prefer to modify the `bar` function to return a `dict`.

```
dict(zip(['one', 'two', 'three'], bar()))
```

Comment: I think they downvoted you because your solution only captures the keys of the dictionary returned by the bar function but assigns them to the values of the produced dictionary.  I did not downvote you, however, so I'm just conjecturing.